# Linux freezes randomly

Tags: linux, fedora

I have an Acer Aspire ES1-311 Intel Pentium N3540 Quad Core 8GB 500GB 13.3 Laptop ever since I installed `Fedora 23` it keeps freezing randomly even sometimes during installation, but I noticed if I go back to `Fedora 22` it happens less frequently. I make sure its well ventilated, tested the ram, even installing a work around 'driver' for the graphics card -- it still won't stop.

Comment: what about hard-disk?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me I have been doing it from a long time. The link helped me understand. I will make sure it wont happen again

Comment: Why is it tagged opensuse and ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

if you make install with USB key, do it with small iso or CD (net-install) if it is possible, load all in memory before starting the installation.
It's a problème with the power on the USB port.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [bug 109051](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) for possible workarounds. Also keep in mind that Fedora 23 support will end one month after Fedora 25 is released in November. You may want to try Fedora 24 or a later spin of Fedora 23 with a higher kernel.